# Is it possible to instruct hibernate not to set null values while performing insert?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "message")
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "subject")
    private String subject;

    @Column(name = "content")
    private String content;

    @Column(name = "html")
    private String html;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private Integer status;

    @Column(name = "creation_date")
    private Date creationDate;

    @Column(name = "send_date")
    private Date sendDate;

    //GET, SET
}
```

The table `message` has the following definition for the column creation_date:

```
creation_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now()\
```

As a conslusion, when I don't set a specific value to `creation_date`, hibernate will generate a query which looks like as follows:

```
insert into partner.message (content, creation_date, email, html, send_date, status, subject) 
values ('text', null, 'text', 'text', null, '1', 'text')
```

Is it possible to avoid generating those `null`-values?

BTW, I'm on `PostgreSQL`. Does it have something to do with `PostgreSQL`-dialect?

Comment: have you tried @Column(name = "" ,nullable=false) ?

Comment: @Saif No, I've not. Why did you put the empty string as the name attribute?

Comment: yes  there goes the name attribute like @Column(name = "column_name" ,nullable=false)

Comment: @user3663882 it's possible, but it's a bad idea. You would end up with an entity, in memory, which has a null timestamp, although the corresponding column has a non-null value generated by the database. To be consistent, you would have to tell Hibernate to re-read the entity from the database after every insert (which is also possible). That would not be very efficient. You'd better generate the timestamp in the application and create the entity with a non-null value.

Comment: @JBNizet How can I tell hibernate to re-read the entity after every insert if I can't even perform the insert operation. An exception is thrown during that. So, the best solution would be setting the actual `creation_date` value from `Java`, huh?

Comment: Right, like I stated in my answer.

Comment: What exactly prevents you from setting the date to the current time during initialisation/[@PrePersist/@PreUpdate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/listeners.html#d0e2985)? It would have the advantage to be database independent and a lot easier to change in future versions.

Comment: @user3663882 using https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/DynamicInsert.html to avoid inserting null, and then https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Generated.html to force Hibernate to re-read the state. But I repeat: I would not do this. I would instead initialize the timestamp in the entity.

Comment: Here's an example for "dynamic-insert": https://mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-dynamic-insert-attribute-example/
Don't forget to follow @JBNizet recomendations.

Answer (score 5):

You should set your column `creationDate` as non nullable:

```
@Column(name = "creation_date", nullable = false)
private Date creationDate;
```

IIRC, Hibernate should throw an exception when doing an insert if it is null. This way you have to make sure it is always set.

Another option is to have a default value for creationDate:

```
@Column(name = "creation_date", nullable = false)
private Date creationDate = new Date(); //Or set it in the constructor
```